# perl getting 0 instead of output

Tags: perl, if-statement, curly-braces

the file I am working with has the following information in the columns
trying to get the name, average, min and max of each name

```
Name,   Category,    Assignment,  Score,   Possible,
Al,        test,        T1,         90,      100
Ben,       test,        T1,        80,      100
Al ,      lab,         L1,         76,      100
Ben,       lab,         L1,         67,      100
```

the first issue I had with the code was it kept saying there was an illegal division at line 25, I changed some stuff around and now I'm getting

```
Name Average Min Max0
```

as my output instead of anything actually being done math wise
I'm not really sure where my issues are

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %total;
my %count;
my %min;
my %max;
while(<>){
    chomp;
    @fields = split(/,/, $_);
    if(@fields[0] !~ /Student/){
        $total{@fields[2]} += @fields[5];
        $count{@fields[5]}++;
    }
    if($min{@fields[2]} > @fields[5]){
        $min{@fields[2]} = @fields[5];
    } elsif($min{@fields}[2] == 0){
        $min{@fields[2]} = @fields[5];
    }
    if($max{@fields[2]} < @fields[5]){
        $max{@fields[2]} = @fields[5]
    }
}
print "Name\tAverage\tMin\tMax";
foreach $total(keys %count){
    print $total . "\t" . $total{$type}/$count{$type} . $min{$type} . "\t" . $min{$type} . "\t". $max{$type} . "\n";
}
```

the expected output

```
Name Average   Low High
Q1       83    76    90
L1       73.5  67    80
```

Comment: Why do you use 6 fields when your data only has 5 fields?

Comment: oh whoops my bad I forgot to add them in my file!

Comment: You can't add the string `T1` to a number `100`. Add `use strict; use warnings;` to your code and fix the errors that appear.

Comment: I went ahead and added it in there

Comment: With provided sample data `$fields[5]` is `undef` as it does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

The major problems:

- You never assign anything to `$type`. (It's not even declared).
- `%count` only has one element because `@fields[5]` is always undefined because your data only has 5 fields.
- `$total` isn't the count; it's (the stringification of) the value returned by `@fields[5]`.
- You don't emit a line feed after your header.

ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score -2):

OP's mistakes already was described, next code demonstration how to utilize hash to name fields of data. This approach should make code easier to read and understand and will not require to count what number is for a particular field.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @fields = qw/Name Category Assignment Score Possible/;
my(%data,$result);

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /$fields[0]/;
    @data{@fields} = split(/[\s,]+/,$_);
    $result->{$data{Assignment}}{min} = $result->{$data{Assignment}}{min} // 100;
    $result->{$data{Assignment}}{max} = $result->{$data{Assignment}}{max} // 0;
    $result->{$data{Assignment}}{min} = $data{Score}
        if $data{Score} < $result->{$data{Assignment}}{min};
    $result->{$data{Assignment}}{max} = $data{Score}
        if $data{Score} > $result->{$data{Assignment}}{max};
    $result->{$data{Assignment}}{total} += $data{Score};
    $result->{$data{Assignment}}{count}++;
}

my @header = qw/Name Average Low High/;
say join("\t",@header);

for( sort keys %$result ) {
    say join("\t",
                (   
                    $_,
                    $result->{$_}{total}/$result->{$_}{count},
                    $result->{$_}{min},
                    $result->{$_}{max}
                )
            );
}

__DATA__
Name,   Category,    Assignment,  Score,   Possible,
Al,        test,        T1,         90,      100
Ben,       test,        T1,        80,      100
Al ,      lab,         L1,         76,      100
Ben,       lab,         L1,         67,      100
```

Or shorter version

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $result;

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^Name/;
    my($assig,$score) = (split(/[\s,]+/,$_))[2,3];
    $result->{$assig}{min} = $result->{$assig}{min} // 100;
    $result->{$assig}{max} = $result->{$assig}{max} // 0;
    $result->{$assig}{min} = $score
        if $score < $result->{$assig}{min};
    $result->{$assig}{max} = $score
        if $score > $result->{$assig}{max};
    $result->{$assig}{total} += $score;
    $result->{$assig}{count}++;
}

my @header = qw/Name Average Low High/;
say join("\t",@header);

for( sort keys %$result ) {
    say join("\t",
                (   
                    $_,
                    $result->{$_}{total}/$result->{$_}{count},
                    $result->{$_}{min},
                    $result->{$_}{max}
                )
            );
}

__DATA__
Name,   Category,    Assignment,  Score,   Possible,
Al,        test,        T1,         90,      100
Ben,       test,        T1,        80,      100
Al ,      lab,         L1,         76,      100
Ben,       lab,         L1,         67,      100
```

Output

```
Name    Average Low     High
L1      71.5    67      76
T1      85      80      90
```

Comment: I purposefully didn't do their homework for them.

Comment: That's a lot of repeated typing there.